# Python - Animating a numerical solution to the wave equation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a solution to the wave equation - I am plotting the stress and the displacement against x, but I want it to evolve with time.

I *think* a solution would be to treat every position x as a single 'particle' and then have that particle obey the function that defines y, and animate that in t? However, the only way I'm seeing to implement this seems a bit too brute force, leading to bulky code for what should really be short and easy.

I intend to extend this code to allow for mu and rho to be variables dependent upon position as opposed to constants, but for now I just want to get the animation working.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Definition of parameters
dt = 0.04
t = np.arange(0.0,40,dt)
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000) # x position
Y0 = np.array([0,10])       # initial conditions
mu = 1.5
rho = 1.2
omega = 1
def dY_dx(Y, t=0):
    """ Return the gradient of y1 and y2"""
    return np.array([Y[1] / mu, - (omega ** 2) * rho * Y[0]])

from scipy import integrate

Y = integrate.odeint(dY_dx, Y0, x)

y1, y2 = Y.T

# set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(0,15), ylim=(-10,10))
ax.grid()

line1, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', ms=2)
line2, = ax.plot([], [], '-', lw=2)
time_template = 'time = %.lfs'
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

# initialisation function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line1, line2, time_text

# animation function: this is called sequentially
def animate(i):

    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)

    time_text.set_text(time_template%(i*dt))
    return line1, line2, time_text

# call the animator. blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, len(Y)), interval=25, blit=True, init_func=init)

#ani.save('waveEquation.mp4', fps=15)
plt.show()
```

I have tried:

```
# animation function: this is called sequentially
def animate(i):

    line1.set_data(x[i], y1[i])
```

and

```
# animation function: this is called sequentially
def animate(i):

    line1.set_data(x, y1[i])
```

but neither give the result I desire.

Could the issue be that I am integrating my solutions over t before they are plotted, and then not including t as a variable in my animation?

I know I can use code (found on a similar question here):

```
def animate(i):
    thisx = x
    thisy = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))

    line1.set_data(thisx, thisy)
```

to animate a sin wave, but I don't want to be using an analytic solution to calculate y, I want to do it numerically (for later problems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConorB,

You asked:

> Could the issue be that I am integrating my solutions over `t` before
>   they are plotted, and then not including `t` as a variable in my
>   animation?

Yes, that is precisely your issue. The `animate` definition should include updating of `t`, and then--presumably--should require re-integration and recalculation of the lines to plot, `y1` and `y2`. It's hard to know exactly what you want your plot to show, without additional knowledge of the general problem domain, but your `animate` function should look something like this:

```
def animate(i):
    t = np.arange(0.0,40,dt) + i*dt
    Y = integrate.odeint(dY_dx,Y0,t)
    y1,y2 = Y.T

    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)

    time_text.set_text(time_template%t)
    return line1, line2, time_text
```

Also, your code wouldn't run, due to invocations of `array` instead of `np.array` and some errant whitespace. I cleaned it up, pending peer-review.

Comment: This has helped - with a couple of adjustments to my code, I now have managed to almost get exactly what I wanted. The animation now translates across my screen (due to the incrementing of x (note: I had mislabelled a couple of things, and should have been integrating against x)). 

However, what would be ideal is if there were a way to loop the array index back to the start when the x value goes outside the range I have defined. By this I mean, incrementing x[999] will send it back to x[0]. 

Many thanks!

Comment: ConorB, use the modulo operator `%` to keep the counter between 0 and 999, e.g. `counter=(counter+1)%1000`.